# Url.Content on Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, azure

I have an ASP.NET MVC 2 application that has page with a link to a pdf file

```
<a href="<%= Url.Content("~/Downloads/test1.pdf") %>">test1</a>
```

Downloads directory is at MVCApplication1/Downloads

This works fine locally and on ISS, but returns a page not found when uploaded to Azure.

Comment: Probably a stupid question but did you upload the PDF file as well?

Comment: Yes the pdfs were uploaded aswell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In visualstudio in the pdf properties had to change the Build Action to Content and Copy to Output Dir to Copy always for this to work with Azure

Comment: When I changed both ( Build Action to Content and Copy to Output Dir to Copy always ), I couldn't publish the app anymore. So I only leave the Build Action setting to "Content" and Copy to Output Directory to "Do not copy" and it now works.

Answer (score 2):

Check the path that is being emitted in the HTML.  Its likely relative to the Azure datacenter/cluster, and is meaningless to your client if your client is outside Azure.

If you see something like "http://RD1204900029029/Downloads/test1.pdf", thats your issue.  You'll need to emit the actual path using application logic to account for some of the magic the load-balancer does on your behalf.

Best way to use URL information provided by the request itself.  I'm not an ASP.NET master by any means, so there may be a cleaner way to do this (similar to Url.Content) but this will work

Try

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host
```

so

```
<%
    var host = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host;
%>

<a href="<%= host + "/Downloads/test1.pdf" %>">test1</a>
```

Comment: Yes I am getting "http://RD1204900029029.cloudapp.net/Downloads/test1.pdf". How would I emit the actual path?

Comment: The above code results in:An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.HttpContext.Request.get'

Comment: Sorry, was off top of my head, you'll have to grab the current context, so System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host.  Edited my answer to reflect

Answer (score 1):

This is a guess...

But I think that perhaps the Azure IIS instance does not include PDF as a known MIME type.

To adjust for this try adding the mime type to your app's web.config file:
http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2008/03/25/how-to-add-mime-types-with-iis7-web-config.aspx

If this still doesn't work, then maybe consider:

- changing the file extension
- moving the PDF to Blob storage - in theory it should be more efficient to serve this static content direct from Blob storage
- adding a dynamic proxy to your app for this file (not ideal!)