# img src inside MVC View does not work. Could not find the path

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, model-view-controller

```
<img src="/content/images/page/looding.gif" >
```

Within another .cshtml, same image tag works fine. But it fails on this one. Gives the error:
Could not find a part of the path 'C:\content\images\page\looding.gif'. I tried this:

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/page/fastercv-logo.png")"
```

I got same error. Any suggestion?

Comment: Which version of MVC are you using?

Comment: MVC Version is: 3.0.0.0

Comment: On your first attempt, using pure html markup you should try adding 
`<img src="../content/images/page/fastercv-logo.png" />`, otherwise, you should your entire view to get a bit more help

Comment: Made a little difference. Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Content\images\page\fastercv-logo.png'. Add Program Files (x86). What more do you need to see from the view?

Comment: For some reason it's looking for the file in the wrong folder structure and not in your application root folder, interesting...where do you have your application deployed?

Comment: See if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076846/url-content-on-azure